# LinkedIn API - Search Professionals by Skills

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Is there a LinkedIn API that return the list of professionals by skills, roles, or a combination of  both?

If so, what are the requirements and process to get access to this API?

Any help or insights would be much greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, LinkedIn gives only the scope of r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress to Retrieve authenticated member's name, headline, photo, and member's primary email address.

To get the list of professionals by skills, roles, or a combination of both, etc, for that you need the permission of r_fullprofile,

LinkedIn API has restricted such information as per their documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile
[image]

As per their documentation, to access the information of skills, address, etc, your app needs to request r_fullprofile. But they have closed it now and no alternate is given. The more detail about the current permissions from LinkedIn can be seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access

Right now there are currently in development mode. They are working on developing their APIs. What and when they will release such information is not available to document right now.